# Map vs listable

Tags: map, attributes

What's the difference between setting a function's attribute as `Listable` and using `Map`? I understand that `Map` is more specific, the question is rather about action on single depth lists.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The main difference can been seen when dealing with list of lists. Consider the following list:

```
lis = {{1, 2, 3}, {3, 4, 5}, {5, 6, 7}};
```

Lets create a `Listable` function `g`

```
SetAttributes[g, Listable]
```

Now we `Map` a non-listable function `f` and apply the listable function `g`

```
Map[f, lis]

(* {f[{1, 2, 3}], f[{3, 4, 5}], f[{5, 6, 7}]} *)

g[lis]

(* {{g[1], g[2], g[3]}, {g[3], g[4], g[5]}, {g[5], g[6], g[7]}} *)
```

Clearly the `Listable` function `g`, continues until it's applied down to a non-list expression. Whereas `Map` by default applies to `Level` 1. One can get the same behavior with `Map` by using the 3rd argument (level specification):

```
Map[f, lis, {2}]

(* {{f[1], f[2], f[3]}, {f[3], f[4], f[5]}, {f[5], f[6], f[7]}} *)
```

On Single-depth lists, they both behave the same:

```
lis2 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};

Map[f, lis2]
g[lis2]

(*
   {f[1], f[2], f[3], f[4], f[5], f[6]}
   {g[1], g[2], g[3], g[4], g[5], g[6]} 
*)
```

Performance does not seem to vary much either. Consider the following functions:

```
SetAttributes[k, Listable];
k[x_]:= x^2 + 2x
u[x_]:= x^2 + 2x
```

Let's apply them to a large list:

```
lis3 = RandomReal[2, 10^6];
k[lis3]; // RepeatedTiming
Map[u, lis3]; // RepeatedTiming

(* {1.26, Null}    
   {1.242, Null} *)
```

Of course, if you are going to use `Map`, you're better off using a pure function since that increases performance by a lot:

```
Map[#^2 + 2 # &, lis3]; // RepeatedTiming
```

> {0.065, Null}

To be fair, I should also mention that you can make a `Listable` pure function (see comments) that performs about the same as `Map` with a pure function.
As Szabolcs mentioned in the comments here is an example where the `Listable` version appears to have no `Map` counterpart:

```
g[{1, {2, 3}, 4, h[x]}]

(* {g[1], {g[2], g[3]}, g[4], g[h[x]]} *)
```

So at least, that's a difference. And I'm sure one can come up with many such examples.

Comment: If you define `k` and `u` as `#^2 + 2 # &`, set `k` to be `Listable`, and then do `k[lis3]` vs `u /@ lis3`, my machine says that the former is even faster.

Comment: @march. On mine it's slower, but I should probably mention that option too to be fair.

Comment: `g[{1, {2, 3}, 4, f[x]}]` is a good example to include too.  This cannot be done with `Map` at all, not even by mapping at level -1.

Comment: @Szabolcs it comes close, oh so close. `{f[1], {f[2], f[3]}, f[4], h[f[x]]}`

Comment: @Szabolcs. Thanks, I included your example.